# Random Values when returning php echo to JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm having a weird issue when returning variables from PHP To Javascript  I have a ajax call to a function as seen below(I am using CodeIgniter):

```
public function automaticEnd(){
    $this->load->model('test_model');
    $this->test_model->addResult("common");
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    echo "success/";
}
```

In my AJAX call I simply want to see an alert box appear with success/

```
                    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/project/main/automaticEnd",
                    data: data,
                    success: function(msg){
                        alert(msg);
                    }
                 });
```

however I am seeing an output such as:
"0:12:14success/"

anyone seen this issue before? any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem relies in the `addResult()` method of your `test_model`.

Check to see if there is another echo statement in there.

The string before "success/" looks like time. Maybe you echo a value there for testing purposes.

Comment: ok thankyou I will take a look - I'm sure it must be something small